# Creating an array of non-square rectangles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to create equal sized rectangles joined like the picture below with labels centered above. I've tried looking for other answers but they all seem to be arrays of squares.

[image]

Comment: Just add '[xscale=2]'

Comment: @BlackMild thank you so much, it works perfectly

Comment: Can you provide more context on this? Is it part of a larger figure/table, or something stand-alone?

Comment: @Werner its standalone, I just needed a way to stick a certain number of those rectangles together and put a centered label on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options to do that, see two of them below. Adjust the values as you want and that's all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\rule{1cm}{0pt}}& \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\rule{1cm}{0pt}} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\rule{1cm}{0pt}} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3} 
  \draw (\x,0) rectangle node[above=.2cm]{\x} ++(1,-0.5) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this